# ASP.NET 5 Web API application intermittently unresponsive

Tags: amazon-ec2, asp.net-core-webapi

We are working on an ASP.NET 5 Web API project that is in production now but we are experiencing an issue where it becomes unresponsive intermittently throughout the day.

A few notes about the application architecture. It is an ASP.NET Web API project using a MariaDB database on a separate EC2 instance within the same private network. The connection string uses the private IP of the database server to avoid any name resolution issues. The site is hosted via IIS 10.

The application itself has been developed carefully following the best practices provided by Microsoft. Heavy focus on async operations, minimizing query response times and offloading more expensive operations into background services.

The app is extremely responsive. It performs with sub 100ms responses on almost all requests, even the more complicated requests, and all the way up until it becomes unresponsive this high level of performance remains the same. We tend to see between 10-30 requests per second and 300-500 select queries per second at peak usage so not too extreme. However, randomly (2-3 times over a 24 hour period) it will begin hanging on requests and simply not respond to the request. During this time, the database is still extremely responsive and we are never over 300 connections out of our 512 connection limit.

The resources on the application server itself are never really taxed much at all. The CPU never gets above ~20% and the memory usage sits around 20-30%.

If I were to stop the site in IIS and start it again while this is happening, it will quickly come back online. If I don't it will be down for a few minutes until IIS finally kills it due to a failed health check. There are no real errors generated as a response to the issue other than typical errors caused by the hanging of the process such as connection terminated errors. The only thing I have seen before that gave me pause was the fact that there a few connection timeouts when getting the connection from the pool, but like I said, the connections to the server are never close to the limit.

Also, this app and version has been in production for months and it wasn't until the traffic volume started to grow that we started seeing these issues. At this point, I am at a loss for next steps of troubleshooting and I'm seeking suggestions.

Comment: `until the volume started to grow` - id start there. Check the metrics on your disks themselves as well as the ec2 instance. How big is your volume / how full? Is there anything relevant in the HTTPERR logs (in windows folder) or the System/Application logs in Event Viewer? Do your IIS access logs give any clues what IIS was doing before it hung / any patterns? Could be file locking or other concurrency issue? Do you have an anti virus installed?

Comment: @MisterSmith sorry that was supposed to read "traffic volume". There is virtually no disk access once the assemblies are loaded when the application is running. That is all offloaded to S3, DyanmoDB or the main MariaDB database. There is absolutely nothing in the logs except for the process being terminated for being unresponsive and the new process starting.

Comment: Do you have stdout logging enabled? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/logging-and-diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Yes it has been enabled the whole time and there is never any output related to the unresponsiveness. Occasionally if we hard terminate the service in the middle of a background task we can create an unrelated error but there is never any output in the log pertaining to the actual issue.

Comment: Can you increase the verbosity of your logs / add additional logging temporarily / are you silently catching exceptions anywhere? Have you done any load/stress testing on your app - ie can you make it crash outside of production?  Last resort i suggest you capture crash dumps of the faulting w3wp process with DebugDiag. A "full dump" (not mini dump) contains the application state at the time of the crash and can be read with WinDbg + symbol files. Analyzing crash-dumps is not trivial (esp background/async), but your issues sounds application specific. Some sort of deadlock under load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a root cause for this issue, however, after updating to newer versions of .NET MVC this issue went away. My best guess is that changes with the Kestrel possibly resolved this issue, although, I have no idea what specific change that might have been. I have gone through the change logs a few times and didn't see anything that specifically jumped out at me.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS App Pool advanced settings set `Start Mode` to `AlwaysRunning`

[image]